# std::vector<bool> with only one true element

Tags: c++, boost, vector, foreach, boolean

I need an `std::vector<bool>`, in which only one element may be true later in the program.
My attempt was ( in a for-loop)

```
BOOST_FOREACH( bool b, boolvector)
{
    b = false;
}
boolvector[j] = true;
```

But when this executes the elements don't get reset to false when doing the BOOST_FOREACH (function of the boost library to iterate more conveniently through containers ( see [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/foreach.html)).

P.S.: I know that std::vector is a broken thing, but it should suffice.

Comment: `I know that std::vector is a broken thing` Is that so ?

Comment: @Nbr44 `std::vector<bool>` is not an instantiation of `std::vector<T>` with `T=bool`. It is a specialisation such that each `bool` only takes `1` bit. This means that it doesn't give you references to the contained `bool`s, it gives you proxy objects. Basically it doesn't behave quite the same way as other instantiations of `std::vector`, and this is widely considered a mistake. "Broken" from a design point of view, not a technical one.

Comment: It looks like a function declaration where bool b is called by value, not reference

Comment: @BoBTFish I see. Probably the wording of that sentence wasn't entirely clear.

Comment: I think you could use `std::bitset` (or `boost::dynamic_bitset`) instead. Did you try it?

Comment: No, I didn't but I've found another (quite simple) solution by using iterators with a for loop.

Comment: I suggest to replace the vector with an index of the true element.

Answer (score 4):

I will try this in a few minutes, but I suspect you want

```
BOOST_FOREACH(std::vector<bool>::reference b, boolvector)
{
    b = false;
}
```

`std::vector<bool>`, as you say, is "broken", and dereferencing an iterator doesn't give you a nice convenient reference, it gives you some proxy object: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Edit: Yes, this works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

void print (const std::vector<bool>& bv)
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    for (auto it = std::begin(bv); it != std::end(bv); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> boolvector {true, false, true, false};
    print(boolvector);

    BOOST_FOREACH(std::vector<bool>::reference b, boolvector)
    {
        b = false;
    }

    print(boolvector);
}
```

Prints:

```
$ ./a.out 
true false true false 
false false false false
```

This:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(auto b, boolvector)
```

also works, but

```
BOOST_FOREACH(auto& b, boolvector)
```

does not (fails to compile due to non-`const` reference to temporary).

However, as Nawaz points out, if you have c++11 support, just ditch `BOOST_FOREACH` entirely, and write:

```
for (auto b : boolvector)
```

**Much later edit:**

I don't know how I missed this in the first place, but it looks like the correct solution here is to use [`assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign):

```
b.assign(b.size(), false);
b[i] = true;
```

Comment: Yeah, I see the error I made now. But isn't it also impossible to get a reference to a single bit?

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yes, you're right. `auto b` [does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b0f72a6b0dae22ef4e33a64e6bd78217-e223fd4a885a77b520bbfe69dda8fb91).

Comment: BTW, if you use `auto`, why use `BOOST_FOREACH` then? You could use range-based `for`. ;-) +1

Comment: @Nawaz Exactly. I was assuming no c++11 in the real code, hence use of `BOOST_FOREACH` in the first place. I used it in my example for convenience, and mentioned `auto` due to comments on a now-deleted answer.